How do I send a parameter with the method in wire:click securely?
In my Laravel web application, I have a button that sends a friend request from the Auth user to the recipient. I want to pass the recipient's id in the method, but when I inspect the code, I can change the parameter data.
<button 
    wire:click="sendFriendRequest({{ $user->id }})"
    class="bg-blue-500 text-white font-semibold py-2 px-4 rounded hover:bg-blue-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-300"
>
    Send Friend Request
</button>

The friend request method:
public function sendFriendRequest($id) {
   $recipient = User::find($id);
   $sender = Auth::user();

   $sender->befriend($recipient);
}


You can encrypt the $user->id and then in sendFriendRequest($id) method you decrypt it.In this way you securely send parameter.

Or you can store the $user->id into session and then make use of it.TO do so you nee to able to understand that at which point you need to store the user id.

If the user changes the value to another recipient, it will simply send a request to the wrong person. Probably the user won't do that because it doesn't help them - presumably they really wanted the request to go to somebody else. But if your application has some rules about who people can send friend requests to, then your server-side code need to validate this data when it receives the request. You can't stop users tampering with anyhing which is in their browser, but you can stop incorrect/invalid data from being actioned by the server when it receives it.

@ADyson So if it was a more sensitive situation, for example, and needed to pass a post id or user id as the paramter, will the encryption/decryption method be a good approach for handling the security of the data? For example, the article here

@WPdev11 It might be helpful, to make it harder for the user to guess other IDs - but again if they happen to have seen an encrypted ID of another item somehow (it could easily happen) they could still try switching to that ID in another context when they're not supposed to. So ultimately you still must have server-side validation of the input data against your business rules and authorisation rules, to make sure any request makes sense and is permitted. The encryption is not a solution by itself.

There is a way to automatically encrypt and decrypt model ids which livewire respects.
Just let laravel handle the encryption for you by adding this to the model
/**
 * Automatic primary key encryption.
 *
 * @return string The encrypted primary key of the model.
 */
public function getRouteKey(){
    return $this->exists ? encrypt($this->getKey()) $this->getKey();
}

/**
 * Automatically decrypt the model field
 *
 * @param mixed $value The encrypted field value.
 * @param string|null $field The name of the field to decrypt. Defaults to the model primary key.
 * @return mixed The resolved model.
 */
public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null){
    return $this->where((is_null($field) ? $this->getKey() : $field), decrypt($value))->first();
}

Use automatic encryption/decryption
Then for your button, don't send the id, just pass the model:
<button wire:click="sendFriendRequest({{ $user }})" class="bg-blue-500 text-white font-semibold py-2 px-4 rounded hover:bg-blue-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-300">
    Send Friend Request
</button>

Then for the controller method just use the passsed model:
/**
 * Send a Friend Request to a user
 *
 * Not sure user if the typehinted class (User) is actually needed
 * for binding to work correctly with livewire but it's a good 
 * practice to typehint arguments.
 *
 * @param User $recipient The User model that will receive a request
 * @return mixed The result of the befriend method. 
 */
public function sendFriendRequest(User $recipient) {
   return auth()->user()->befriend($recipient);
}

If the auto encrypt/decrypt isn't working
Do this for your button:
<button wire:click="sendFriendRequest({{ $user->getRouteKey() }})" class="bg-blue-500 text-white font-semibold py-2 px-4 rounded hover:bg-blue-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-300">
    Send Friend Request
</button>

Use this in the controller:
/**
 * Send a Friend Request to a user
 *
 * @param $recipientId The encrypted id of the user model that will receive a request
 * @throws Exception If the User model could not be loaded.
 * @return mixed The result of the befriend method. 
 */
public function sendFriendRequest($recipientId) {
   if($recipient = User::find(decrypt($recipientId)) return auth()->user()->befriend($recipient);
   throw new \Exception('Invalid recipient');
}

